# HTML templates are not sent properly as programmed

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailkit

I am stucked while developing an application in c# for bulk mailing purposes . My application is reading predefined HTML templates with recipients details provided in the html template. My application is generating invoices which in turn replaces the pre defined strings mentioned in the html templates in the fields like <%CUSTOMER_NAME%> , <%INVOICE_NUMBER%> etc. Now the problem is when I send the data using the same methodology mentioned above say 5000 emails of invoives. Data get shuffled and gets replaced in those fields where the pre defined strings are not even mentioned.

Thanks in advance for solving the issue.

I tried using string replace method but no luck. I want that data retrieved from an HTML invoice should be replaced with the data to be sent to the next recipient in the list of recipients taken from the Excel file. Also I am using more than one html invoice formats for sending the data.

Comment: Use a HTML library instead of your replacement method.  HTML is not regular and trying to use REGEX (or similar library) does not always work.